# I want to get google oauth2 token in android app

Tags: android, oauth

By following [this](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) tutorial I have developed an android app. Using google oauth it will login to google+ and fetches profile name and image. Now I want to get the google oauth2 token so that I can pass that token to a web service for logging into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) and give it the GoogleApiClient object as a parameter.  It has a [GetToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method you can use to retrieve an OAuth2 token from Google.  The GoogleAuthUtil page has an example on how to get a token both blocking and asynchronously.